# PlaySound in C++ using CLion

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide, playsound

I am trying to make a simple C++ program that plays music, but I'm getting this error.

`undefined reference to __imp_PlaySoundA'`

From what I read I found out that I don't have any source code that implements PlaySound. I know I should add a reference to winmm.lib to my linker, but I only found how to do this in VisualStudio. Is there a way how to do it in CLion? I'm not even sure if CLion has something like that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {  
    PlaySound("file_name.mp3", nullptr, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't help:

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, as the question has been incorrectly closed as a duplicate, in my opinion. The OP states that they want instructions for **configuring CLion** to pass a certain library to the linker. They do not want general information on the reason why libraries have to be passed to the linker.

Comment: Try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#link-libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved it, you need to add winMM.Lib to the CMake file. Plus the file can't be .mp3 but .wav (maybe some others, I did't try).

```
# Link to GLFW, GLEW and OpenGL
target_link_libraries(template PUBLIC
        ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        winMM.Lib)
```